# Google App Engine, Handling of Python Lists - Error accessing List Index[0][0]

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having an issue on Google App Engine that is pretty weird.  I have small text file, its 311kbs.  The text inside needs parsed.  My code works fine running local, but when I push it out to GAE, it fails. I've shortened it to the below simple example, to show what breaks.  The code below fails at writing out what should be in splitlist[0][0], interestingly, if try splitlist[0] it prints out the entire text file.

```
import webapp2
import os, re

#Load the text file...
file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'TextFileEN.txt')
openfile=open(hymnfile)
text=openfile.read()
#List for split text
splitlist=[]

#Split text on the consistent 4 carriage returns.
textsplit=splitlist.append(text.split('\n\n\n\n'))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.out.write(splitlist[0][0])

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

This kind of pattern is created by the splitlist.append(text.split()) command [["item1", "item2", "item3",]] when I run it local, and I can access the item like this splitlist[0][0] gives me "item1".  I've tried this with Python25 and Python27 on app engine, and when deployed it fails as described above. Any ideas?

Comment: If the `splitlist[0]` prints out the entire text file, then `splitlist[0][0]` should return the first character, rather than failing. You said it fails at writing out "what should be". Could you explain what it should be and what the file looks like? (I would also recommend specifying `r` or `rU` as your file mode in open.)

Comment: Instead of telling us "it fails", show us the stacktrace. Don't make us guess what's going wrong, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that something happened to your text file when uploading?

It looks like split is not recognizing the '\n\n\n\n'.

Comment: I figured something was happening to the format when uploading I just couldn't figure out what:)  Between you and bossylobster, I figured it out, I'd forgotten the 'rU' flag, and that got me past this error.